# gawk match function parameter as regular expression

Tags: regex, awk

I encounter error when I use gawk. Below is the my script and example file
Can you guys help me? I think regex is right but there is an error when it passed to the match function. I try various approach such as give \ to special character of regex or double .

$ cat script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
gawk '
BEGINFILE{
        while( getline < FILENAME > 0 ){
                print match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?= ops/s)/)
                print $0
        }
}
' ./file
```

$ cat file

```
123.456: IO Summary: 123456 ops 1234.567 ops/s 100/100 rd/wr   1.0mb/s 1.111ms/op
```

$ sh script.sh

```
gawk: cmd. line:4: error: Unmatched ( or \(: /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?= ops/
```

Comment: If you [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input then we can't help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way (and it won't be a while/getline/match loop in a BEGINFILE section!). That's not a safe way to call `getline` btw - see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex in `awk` or `gnu-awk` don't support lookaheads. You can use this alternative `gnu-awk` command:

```
awk 'match($0, /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) ops\/s/, m) {print m[1]}' file

1234.567
```

Here is POSIX compliant awk command to do the same:

```sh
awk 'match($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ops\/s/) {
   print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH-6)}' file

1234.567
```

However if there can be multiple matches per line then use:

```sh
awk '{
   s = $0
   while (match(s, /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) ops\/s/, m)) {
      print m[1]
      s = substr(s, RSTART + RLENGTH)
   }
}' file
```

Comment: (These are nice and informative solutions :-) )

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples could you please try following. This should match digit with and without floating points here.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? +ops\/s/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ .*/,"",val)
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? +ops\/s/){    ##using match function to match regex [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? +ops\/s in current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)           ##Creating val variable here which has sub string of matched regex from current line.
  sub(/ .*/,"",val)                       ##Substituting everything from space to till last with NULL in val here.
  print val                               ##Printing val here.
}
' Input_file                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk with a `for` loop to slow it down instead of regex. It outputs the match and the record as would your `while` in the sample code. If I misassumed your intention, please update the expected output to the original question:

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)        # loop from second field to the end
        if($i=="ops/s")       # if ith field is ops/s
            print $(i-1)      # print previous field
}1' file                      # output the record
```

Output:

```
1234.567
123.456: IO Summary: 123456 ops 1234.567 ops/s 100/100 rd/wr   1.0mb/s 1.111ms/op
```

Comment: You catch my intention. Thanks for helping!